# Please reconsider this known-good audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I failed this audit today: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/32152758

The rationale for me closing, as lacks details, was that it included the error messages as an image, not even inlined, instead of as text.

The community shouldn't have to type error messages over from a screenshot that's OP's responsability.

I don't mind failing an audit here and there, so no need to roll anything back, but lets not use this one again, please

Comment: Take action on it outside of the review system so that it isn't a valid audit anymore.

Comment: Someone put a downvote on the audit's question now - so it will no longer be "known-good audit". (Since the image is not "picture of the code" and tech is not I'm familiar with  I don't know if image is required to understand the question or purely supplemental - based on votes it is quite possible that problem is well understood by title alone... but I can't definitely provide it as "answer" here)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  No one *should've* put a downvote on the question.  The question is still appropriate for the site and is a good audit for IDE-style questions, which tend to bend the conventions a bit.

Comment: When trying to solve something that involves an error message, it is *imperative* that you include the error message(s) in plain text for searchability, regardless of how inconvenient it may be.

Comment: I agree with you that it's always best for questions to include the full, exact text of an error– but the OP of this one did include the keywords and gist of the error in both their title and their question body. Whether this truly warrants closure or not is borderline, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Given that this looks like an IDE-specific problem, there's really not a lot of "text" to put into the box.  Sometimes you're not afforded an opportunity to copy those messages into a paste buffer when you see them, so a screenshot in those cases is the next best thing.

Maybe what would help is if we actually put the images in the question rather than just the link?

Comment: Well as an OP you are expected to put some effort into your question. Transcribing these few lines wouldn't be too much to ask IMHO.

Comment: IDE questions have a bit of a checkered history here @Luuklag; in most cases yes, we want the text as much as possible as that can be indexed, but if there's enough text *around* what the error is and the image shows the *specific* error, that's generally OK.  Note that I'm not the OP on this - haven't had to mess with XCode in damn near 10 years - but I have dealt with IntelliJ questions in this similar vein.

Comment: This is still infinitely better than when OP just screenshots the entire IDE window.